# Accessing multidimensional arrays in POST data

Tags: php, arrays, post, multidimensional-array

in my app POST variable contains some arrays. How can I loop POST variable to get the arrays data which are keys in  POST variable in PHP. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your HTML must be:

```
<form action=":URL:" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="some[0]" value="0" />
    <input type="hidden" name="some[1]" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="some[2]" value="2" />
    <input type="hidden" name="some[3]" value="3" />
    <input type="hidden" name="some[4]" value="4" />
    ...
</form>
```

So then in PHP you can do:

```
if (isset($_POST['some']))
{
    foreach ($_POST['some'] as $key => $value)
    {
        echo $key, $value;
    }
}
```

Here you are... hoping that it was your question.

Answer (score 3):

[This](http://www.phpbuilder.com/board/showthread.php?t=2141404) seems to answer your question, if I understand correctly you have a multidimensional array so `$_POST['mypost'][$i]` where `$i` is the key/index

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
echo "</pre>";
exit;
```

From this output you can easily find the way

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
foreach($_POST as $v)
{
    //DO SOMETHING WITH $v
    ...
}
```

Comment: That would iterate across the $_POST variables, the question asks how to iterate across an array sent by post.

Comment: My fault. The question is worded oddly, I must have misread it.